# Make changes to order overview in Magento backend

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using Magento 1.7 and I'm wondering how I could make changes to the order overview in the backend. It's a fairly simple adjustment where I'd like to put the company name above the client name instead of the other way around, as it is right now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The customer details on the order in the backend are determined by the sort order of the customer fields.
So you need to put a sort order for the company attribute that is lower than the name.
For this you can edit the customer_eav_attribute table, identify the 2 attributes and switch their sort_order.